# R plot Greek letter cannot be shown

Tags: r, plot, fonts, expression

I want the greek letter be displayed in my title, e.g. when I try this:

```
plot(rnorm(10),main=expression(lambda))
```

But the title is blank, the lambda cannot be shown:

[image]

Please help me to fix it. Many thanks!

Comment: It worked fine for  me, try dev.off()

Comment: Works fine for me - might be a locale-based issue which affects which fonts are available?

Comment: I believe it works fine for most of you. It also worked for me before I update MacOS Sierra. I'm not sure whether the font or the encoding is going wrong right now.

Comment: Use Fontbook.app to check for corrupted font files. The usual symptom is finding duplicated fonts and in this case you would be looking to find 2 copies of Symbol.